# Where did registration originate?

Tags: registration

Is there a way to tell if an event registration was made online through the web site form, or if it was entered directly into the system? (By a staff member for example.)

Comment: Please mention magento version and other details if any

Answer (score 0):

Web forms are one way for users to enter data to the system. In Magento, a web form can be in the frontend or backend. To get the user info, including API users (in this case, the user may be a machine), I wrote the following years ago in M1 and is still being used today successfully:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */         
public function getSessionUser()
{
    $remoteAddress = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr(true);
    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
        return array('username'=>$user->getUsername(), 'userrole'=>$user->getRole()->getRoleName(), 'remote_addr'=>$remoteAddress);                    
    } 
    if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customer = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer();
        return array('username'=>$customer->getEmail(), 'userrole'=>$this->__('frontend'), 'remote_addr'=>$remoteAddress);
    }
    if (Mage::getSingleton('api/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $user = Mage::getSingleton('api/session')->getUser();
        return array('username'=>$user->getUsername(), 'userrole'=>$this->__('api'), 'remote_addr'=>$remoteAddress);
    }
    return array('username'=>$this->__('system'), 'userrole'=>$this->__('system'), 'remote_addr'=>$remoteAddress);
}
```

The system user may be is a cron job, but I do not know of a way to verify this.

[edit]
It has just occurred to me that you may be referring to customer registration. If this is the case, the column *Website* in the admin *Manage Customers* is what you need, this column contains the website where the customer was created. If it's created in *Admin*, it's very likely that a staff member created the customer. I say *very likely* because it is possible to register a customer by API or other processes.